# Margins not managed properly

Tags: html, css

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HFCN3/** 
Putting the margins in the class `.ca`, the first element of the `#div` does not apply the margin from the `#div`, but from the whole body. How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda hard to explain, but a margin needs something to bounce on.
It can't bounce on a border of a div, so it bounces on the div.

You can solve it by adding a `padding-top: 6px` to `#div`.

Or you could use Itay's solution, but then I would personally use `overflow: auto`, same effect, but content won't be hidden when the div is suppose to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding:0 and overflow:hidden..

**HTML**

```
<div id="div">
  <div class='ca'>
    Text
  </div>
  <div class='ca'>
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#div
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
}
div .ca
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 6px;
        background-color: red;

}
```

**Outcome**

[image]

Comment: `padding: 0` doesn't do anything, make it 1px or -1px or so. The overflow does the trick in your code. I would however use overflow: auto. Then content won't be hidden when div becomes more content.